# Alter Procedure does not update departmentID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I altered the following procedure to display item inventory by department. However, this does not seem to be updating the department. I am unsure what is wrong with the procedure. Any help?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetWHInventoryValue]
AS
  BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      DECLARE @loccode CHAR(3)
      DECLARE @locationID CHAR(10)

      DELETE FROM DailySummaries
      WHERE  Item = 119;

      DECLARE activeLocations CURSOR FOR
        SELECT warehouseid,
               whcode
        FROM   warehouse
        WHERE  inactive != 'T';

      OPEN activeLocations

      FETCH next FROM activeLocations INTO @locationID, @loccode

      WHILE( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO DailySummaries
                        (Item,
                         Location,
                         Amount,
                         DepartmentID,
                         [Date])
            VALUES     (119,
                        @loccode,
                        0,
                        0,
                        GETDATE());

            DECLARE @whTotal NUMERIC(13, 2)
            DECLARE @itemID CHAR(10)
            DECLARE @itemCost NUMERIC(11, 2)
            DECLARE @departmentID CHAR(12)

            DECLARE whItems CURSOR FOR
              SELECT mst.masterid,
                     mst.replacementcost,
                     mv.inventorydepartmentid
              FROM   masterwh AS wh,
                     [master] AS mst,
                     masterview mv
              WHERE  mst.masterid = wh.masterid
                     AND wh.warehouseid = @locationid
                     AND mv.masterid = mst.masterid
                     AND mv.warehouseid = wh.warehouseid

            OPEN whItems;

            FETCH next FROM whItems INTO @itemID, @itemCost, @departmentID

            WHILE( @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 )
              BEGIN
                  DECLARE @itemQty NUMERIC(11, 2)

                  DECLARE itemQty CURSOR FOR
                    SELECT SUM(mw.qty)
                    FROM   masterwhqty mw,
                           masterview mv
                    WHERE  mw.warehouseid = @locationid
                           AND mw.masterid = @itemID
                           AND mw.qty > 0
                           AND mv.masterid = mw.masterid
                           AND mv.warehouseid = mw.warehouseid
                           AND mv.inventorydepartmentid = @departmentID;

                  OPEN itemQty;

                  FETCH next FROM itemQty INTO @itemQty;

                  UPDATE DailySummaries
                  SET    amount = amount + ( isnull(@itemQty, 0) * @itemCost ),
                         DepartmentID = @departmentID
                  WHERE  Location = @loccode
                         AND Item = 119
                         AND DepartmentID = @departmentID;

                  DEALLOCATE itemQty;

                  FETCH next FROM whItems INTO @itemID, @itemCost, @departmentID
              END

            DEALLOCATE whItems;

            FETCH next FROM activeLocations INTO @locationID, @loccode
        END

      DEALLOCATE activeLocations;
  END
```

Comment: What should be the new value for departmentID?

Comment: It should get that value from the masterview table. It should not be 0.

Comment: Cursors should be avoided. Especially trebly nested ones.

Comment: 99.9% of the time a cursor should not be used for an insert update or delete. You need to start working sets of data and NEVER loop through records again.

Comment: Can you give a starting point on how I can use the sets for this? It would be extremely helpful. I'm completely unsure how I would use this to create a new procedure which uses sets.

Answer (score 3):

This is your UPDATE code:

```
UPDATE DailySummaries SET amount = amount + (isnull(@itemQty,0) * @itemCost), DepartmentID=@departmentID WHERE Location = @loccode AND Item = 119  and DepartmentID=@departmentID;
```

Here I extracted the relevant part only:

```
SET DepartmentID = @departmentID WHERE DepartmentID = @departmentID;
```

Would you notice update with such code?

Comment: You are replacing `DepartmentID` with `@departmentID` **only** when they are **the same** and some other conditions are met. If you do have such cases, then you are replacing some value with exactly the same value.  Clear enough?